# Problem with getting data from firestore and display it on the screen

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write a website with angular and firebase.
The site works so that different users can be created (I added auth.service.ts)
And any registered user will be able to add a contact to the firestore.

**The problem: I'm unable to get the added contact information to appear on the screen.**

*The error I keep getting in the console is:*

> core.js:6241 ERROR FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path.

*my firestore design:*
collection name "users"-> containing document for each user->each user has "contacts" collection-> each contact containing the email,name,phone contacts attributes.

*The following code is from the crud.service.ts file:*

```
export class CrudService {
  constructor(private authservice: AuthService, public fireservices:AngularFirestore) { }
  
  //create_NewContact adds to the 'contacts' collection in firebase, the contact that the user entered as input
  create_NewContact(Record)
  {  
    return this.fireservices.collection('users').doc(this.authservice.currentUserId).collection('contacts').add(Record);
  }

  //get_AllContacts gets the 'contacts' collection from firebase
  get_AllContacts()
  {
    return this.fireservices.collection('users').doc(this.authservice.currentUserId).collection('contacts').snapshotChanges();
  }
.
.
.
}
```

*The following code is from the contact-list.component.ts file:*

```
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit {
  contact: any;
  contactName: string;
  contactEmail: string;
  contactPhone: string;
  message:string;
  
  constructor(private authservice: AuthService,public crudservice:CrudService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.crudservice.get_AllContacts().subscribe(data => {
      this.contact = data.map(c => {
        return {
          id: c.payload.doc.id,
          isEdit: false,
          name: c.payload.doc.data()['name'],
          email: c.payload.doc.data()['email'],
          phone: c.payload.doc.data()['phone'],
        };
      })
      console.log(this.contact);
    });
  }
  
  /*CreateRecord() will fire after the user press the "Create Contact" btn*/
  CreateRecord()
  {
    //The function stores within the relevant fields in "Record" variable, the user's input
    let Record = {};
    Record['name'] = this.contactName;
    Record['email'] = this.contactEmail;
    Record['phone'] = this.contactPhone;
    
    //create_NewContact is defined in crud.service.ts file
    this.crudservice.create_NewContact(Record).then(res => {
      this.contactName = "";
      this.contactEmail = "";
      this.contactPhone = "";
      console.log(res);
      this.message = "Contact data save done";
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
.
.
.
}
```

Do you have ideas how to fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that the value passed to the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method is an empty string.

The problem most probably comes from the fact that, at the moment you call this method, `this.authservice.currentUserId` is null. `currentUserId` is probably null  because the `authservice` object has not finished initializing: see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) for more details.

You should either use the [`onAuthStateChanged` observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) or check that `this.authservice.currentUserId` is not null.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! should I use in onAuthStateChanged observer in contact-list.component.ts file or in crud.service.ts file? @Renaud Tarnec

Comment: It's difficult to answer without a full map of your Angular project showing all the interactions. The observer will be triggered when the sign-in process is complete (i.e. when there is no more objects in an intermediate state) => It is when it is triggered and `user` is not null that you should call your `create_NewContact` or `get_AllContacts` methods.

Comment: Thank you @Renaud Tarnec ! As you suggested, I checked that this.authservice.currentUser is not null:
   `if(this.authservice.currentUser != null)` (in contact-list.component.ts file), There are no errors now!